# Memoized selector update not triggering in composed selector

Tags: javascript, redux, memoization, reselect

I'm using reselect for memoized selectors in a redux environment. Note in the [readme](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect/blob/master/README.md) for reselect that these selectors are composable - that is, one selector can be used by another. Here are my selectors:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const getUser = (state) => state.user;
const getRegions = (state) => state.regions;
const getSelectedRegion = (state) => state.selectedRegion;
const getSeals = (state) => state.seals;
const getSignatures = (state) => state.signatures;

export const userData = createSelector(
  [ getUser, getSeals, getSignatures ],
  (user, seals, signatures) => {
    if(user === null) return user;
    user.seals = seals.filter(seal => seal.userEmail === user.email);
    user.signatures = signatures.filter(signature => signature.userEmail === user.email);
    user.isRoot = user.roles.includes('root');
    user.isEngineer = user.roles.includes('engineer');
    return user;
  }
);

export const sealForSelectedRegion = createSelector(
  [ userData, getSelectedRegion ],
  (user, selectedRegion) => {
    let sealForSelectedRegion = user.seals.find(seal => seal.region === selectedRegion.name);
    return sealForSelectedRegion;
  }
);
```

Note how the `userData` selector is used by the `sealForSelectedRegion` selector. However, using and debugging these selectors has revealed that when `userData` is triggered and produces a new output, `sealForSelectedRegion` is not triggered. My thinking is it should be triggered because its input `userData` has produced an updated result and therefore `sealForSelectedRegion needs to be recalculated. But this doesn't happen.

There is a similar situation presented in the reselect readme linked above. The only difference I can see is that the selectors that are composed in the readme are not exported. In this instance, I want to both export `userData` and use it as an input to sealForSelectedRegion.

So the question is why does an updated output for `userData` not trigger `sealForSelectedRegion`? Is it because `userData` is exported? If so, why is this a problem?

Comment: you have mutated the state, in the userData selector.

Comment: @Utro that fixed it, thanks! If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.